# How do I take a JS array that has some elements that are also arrays and make ALL array elements top level elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I'm sorry if this has been asked, I'm not even sure how best to phrase the question, so I'll do it in code.  Note: I have no control over the source format of the data, so I have to work with it as is...

I have an array that looks like this (the real thing has many entries, hundreds, all mixed like this, with some of the elements being comma separated values others not):

```
var array = ["item1", "item2", "item3, item4", "item5", "item6"]
```

I already know how to make it like this:

```
var array = ["item1", "item2", ["item3", "item4"] , "item5", "item6"]
```

What I need is for it to be like this:

```
var array = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6"]
```

This project uses jQuery 1.7 and the point is to take a static list of data and parse it into a single array for use in the jQuery UI Autocomplete plugin.  Again, I have no control over the format of the keywords (which is what these are) being passed to the client, the application does what it does, I can only work with the client-side code (gotta love compartmentalization, huh?)

Comment: i'm may be stupid but it looks like: i have `x` , and i want it to be equal to `x`

Comment: @Cherniv look at `'item3, item4'` - OP wants them separated in to their own values within the array.

Comment: @Cherniv I have array elements, and I have array elements that are comma separated because the PHP developer on this project is a bit lazy and there's nothing I can do about it because I'm not doing the PHP and have no access to that component.  I need a clean array with every element at the top level. "item3, item4" is not a valid keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the second step to have an array of arrays, just `join` then `split` it by the comma:

```
var array = ["item1", "item2", "item3, item4", "item5", "item6"]
console.log(array.join(',').split(','));
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/59HDX/)

Comment: This is basically the same answer I just arrived at (typing the question gave me a similar idea:

$tags = $.grep($tags,function(item){return(item)}).toString().split(", ").toString().split(",");
I didn't put the part about removing empties, because I already figured that out... and the second split is just some cleanup so I don't end up with " keyword" elements.  I'll give you the credit though ;)

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but you'll be left with a space in front of some items this way. `_item4` instead of `item4` for example.

Comment: @BrianGlaz thats true, but easily fixed with a `replace(\/W/, '')` - assuming there shouldn't be any non-word characters in the string.

Answer (score 3):

Recurse over your *Array*.

```
function flatten(arr) {
    var i = 0, a = [];
    for (; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] instanceof Array) a = a.concat(flatten(arr[i]));
        else a.push(arr[i]);
    }
    return a;
}

var foo = ["item1", "item2", ["item3", "item4"], "item5", "item6"];
flatten(foo);
// ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/Rq5fb/

```
var array = ["item1", "item2", ["item3", "item4"], "item5", "item6"];

var result = [];

for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (typeof array[i] !== "object") {
        result.push(array[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        while(array[i].length)
        {
            result.push(array[i].shift());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just one more way to do it:

```
function flatten (array) {
    function f (a, b) {
        return a.concat(
            (b instanceof Array) ? b.reduce(f, []) : [b]);
    }
    return array.reduce(f, []);
}
```

Comment: I like this solution too, it's like a case study in how to do JavaScript more like Perl.  (I mean that in a good way, since I spend several years as a Perl developer).  while elegant for sure, most people wouldn't understand this function very well, much less follow it, even with documentation.  I like the solution personally, but I'm sticking with really simple join/split solution.